# Get all html data in a tag parent with id or class use php

Tags: php, html

I have the following text:

```
<div id="parent">
      <div class="box1"> content 1</div>
      <div class="box2"> content 1</div>
      <div class="box3"> content 1 <div class="box31"></div></div>
</div>
```

What I've tried:

```
preg_match_all ("/<div id=\"parent\">([^`]*?)<\/div>/", $str_test, $matches);
print_r($matches);exit;
```

I want to get all the content:

```
<div class="box1"> content 1</div>
<div class="box2"> content 1</div>
<div class="box3"> content 1 <div class="box31"></div></div>
```

It is not working and I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/711206) parse HTML with regex. You can and you should do that with `DOMDocument`.

```
$string = '<div id="parent">
      <div class="box1"> content 1</div>
      <div class="box2"> content 1</div>
      <div class="box3"> content 1 <div class="box31"></div></div>
</div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$parentNode = $xpath->query("//div[@id='parent']");

$html = '';
foreach ($parentNode->item(0)->childNodes as $node) {
    $html .= $node->ownerDocument->saveHtml($node);
}

echo $html;
```

The `saveHTML` method allows you to get the whole html from each node of the node parent (`<div id="parent">`).

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/94DEQ).

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use regex, perhaps as a general text parsing not limited to well-formed HTML, then you should:

1. Use `preg_match` instead of `preg_match_all`
2. Lose the `?` in your pattern.

Your desired result should be inside `$matches[1]`.